# dtSearch - Unknown Exception (i2051)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I test dtSearch software, and I got this error:

> Unknown Exception (i2051)

Maybe the files are too big ? What can I do in order to index also this pages ?

```
index.html in C:\download\ Files H4 \mywebsite (size 14,167, type Text)
Not indexed (file could not be accessed).
Additional information: Unknown Exception (i2051)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this great answer from owners, maybe someone need it. In short, there is no more space on the hdd to store these files

> Rob, Re file size: A dtSearch index can hold over 1 terabyte of text.
> Apart from the 1 terabyte limit on the total amount of text in an
> index, the maximum number of documents in a single index is 2 billion.
> Otherwise, your operating system may impose limits on individual file
> size. Please consult the Microsoft Windows user manual for your
> particular operating system.
>
> Re file could not be accessed: Access errors are generated by your
> operating system and/or network (not dtSearch), so we're limited in
> our ability to diagnose or correct them. In this case, the cause may
> be files that are damaged/corrupt, in an unsupported format (see
> Supported Formats) or in a location that you do not have (Windows)
> permissions to access. However, a debug log (dtinfo.zip) may provide
> additional clues that will help in sorting out the access issue.
> Please follow the instructions below exactly and email the debug log
> directly to dtSearch Development at: tech@dtsearch.com
>
> Here's how to create the debug log: 1) In dtDesktop, click
> Start->Programs->dtSearch->Diagnostic Tools. 2) Click the Make Report
> button, complete -all- of the fields and click the Generate button.
> This will open a text file within Windows Notepad, which will be
> included in the debug log. You can close the text file. 3) Click the
> Diagnostic Logging button. 4) Click the Create or Update index button
> to start the dtSearch Index Manager with diagnostic logging. 5)
> Attempt to Update or Create the index. 6) Close the indexer and return
> to the Diagnostic Tools screen, click the Zip listed files for email
> button and email the \dtSearch\UserData\dtInfo.zip file directly to
> dtSearch Development at: tech@dtsearch. com (NOTE: if the .zip is >2
> megs, please refer to the instructions in How to send large files to
> dtSearch ). IMPORTANT: Before Step 5, make sure you see at least one
> dtSearch_Indexer.log file in the dtSearch diagnostic logs box. If not,
> repeat step 4: []  [dtSearch Diagnostic files - dtSearch_Indexer.log
> screenshot] We will contact you as soon as we have evaluated the debug
> log (generally within 1 business day).
>
> [image: dtsearch diagnostic tools]
>
> Please include the serial number of the dtSearch product or evaluation
> you are using (you can find this information in dtDesktop--included
> with all versions of dtSearch--by clicking Help->About dtSearch).,
>
> > Rob, Re file size: A dtSearch index can hold over 1 terabyte of text.
> > Apart from the 1 terabyte limit on the total amount of text in an
> > index, the maximum number of documents in a single index is 2 billion.
> > Otherwise, your operating system may impose limits on individual file
> > size. Please consult the Microsoft Windows user manual for your
> > particular operating system.
> >
> > Re file could not be accessed: Access errors are generated by your
> > operating system and/or network (not dtSearch), so we're limited in
> > our ability to diagnose or correct them. In this case, the cause may
> > be files that are damaged/corrupt, in an unsupported format (see
> > Supported Formats) or in a location that you do not have (Windows)
> > permissions to access. However, a debug log (dtinfo.zip) may provide
> > additional clues that will help in sorting out the access issue.
> > Please follow the instructions below exactly and email the debug log
> > directly to dtSearch Development at: tech@dtsearch.com
> >
> > Here's how to create the debug log: 1) In dtDesktop, click
> > Start->Programs->dtSearch->Diagnostic Tools. 2) Click the Make Report
> > button, complete -all- of the fields and click the Generate button.
> > This will open a text file within Windows Notepad, which will be
> > included in the debug log. You can close the text file. 3) Click the
> > Diagnostic Logging button. 4) Click the Create or Update index button
> > to start the dtSearch Index Manager with diagnostic logging. 5)
> > Attempt to Update or Create the index. 6) Close the indexer and return
> > to the Diagnostic Tools screen, click the Zip listed files for email
> > button and email the \dtSearch\UserData\dtInfo.zip file directly to
> > dtSearch Development at: tech@dtsearch. com (NOTE: if the .zip is >2
> > megs, please refer to the instructions in How to send large files to
> > dtSearch ). IMPORTANT: Before Step 5, make sure you see at least one
> > dtSearch_Indexer.log file in the dtSearch diagnostic logs box. If not,
> > repeat step 4: []  [dtSearch Diagnostic files - dtSearch_Indexer.log
> > screenshot] We will contact you as soon as we have evaluated the debug
> > log (generally within 1 business day).
> >
> > Please include the serial number of the dtSearch product or evaluation
> > you are using (you can find this information in dtDesktop--included
> > with all versions of dtSearch--by clicking Help->About dtSearch).

[image: how to create the debug log dtSearch]